# SharePoint Online - Can we restrict a user from copying files/documents?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, permissions, document, json-formatting

Simply, I would like to know if we can restrict a user from copying files/documents while allowing them to move them around.

[image]

As I understand, we can display/hide buttons using JSON formatting, but imagine I have to do them one-by-one for dozens of Doc libraries.

https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2022/03/hide-button-in-sharepoint-online-list-or-document-library.html

Another limitation is that, the user can go to OneDrive and use the copy functionality as below:

[image]

Will it be possible to control it through permission or there is a limitation in this functionality?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is not possible using SharePoint permissions as you want to allow users to move files but not copying the files.

For moving files from document library, you need Contribute or higher permissions (with delete permissions) on document library.

And when you grant contribute or higher permissions on document library, user will automatically have permissions to copy files as well.

---

As you already know, you have to do it using JSON view formatting like:

```
{
  "commandBarProps": {
    "commands": [
      {
        "key": "copyTo",
        "hide": true
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

If you don't want to do it manually, you can use PowerShell to apply this JSON formatting to multiple document libraries.